# best bitbucket git sourcetree workflow

Tags: git, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree, branching-and-merging

So far we have a git repo with a master branch. And now we are going to have a QA branch to this repo. (They are stored in bitbucket/git.) I and others use Sourcetree and command line git.

Up until now, the way I worked after cloning the master repo locally was to save my changes through my IDE to the local filesystem. I would open sourcetree and see the files I have changed. I would stage them. Then I would commit. I would push next. They of course committed to master where all the other developers and I were integrated.

But now after our work is peer reviewed I need to push my work to QA. Is the best way to do this (or only way?) to clone test locally. Then after my work is approved in master open sourcetree, switch to QA, and then stage/commit/push? Or should I commit/push changes from master to QA directly?

Are there advantages/disadvantages of either approach?

Answer (score 0):

#### Your workflow

This is going to get you in trouble soon if it hasn't already.

There are groups that can function like you mention above, but in my experience, those 
are developers with years of experience working **together**.

Eventually one developer will have a merge conflict, and remove/add code that shouldn't be. This merge conflict will get added to the main history and will cause headaches. This is a great way to introduce bugs or, more commonly, break the build.

Branches are not enemies, nor are they expensive. They are simply pointers to commits. Branches can be easily made and removed, embrace them as a team.

#### Github Flow

I would recommend starting with the [github flow](https://guides.github.com/introduction/flow/), and molding it to what fits your group. This lets you work in a safe branch that can be appropriately merged to each environment (production/qa).

In a perfect world you will branch from master, do your work, make your commits, and open a pull/merge request to QA. Once reviewed your code is deployed to QA. Once all the work is completed on QA, QA can be merged into master.

#### Other things to consider (the business)

Depending on your work environment you can make your branches more detailed. For example, while working at an agency, you may have to bill for a feature before it can be deployed. You don't want to stop bug fixes from going out because of that. You could be on a product team where master must always be ready to deploy for a new client, or be an example of what is on production so bugs can be identified easily.

Comment: So how does a merge of a branch forego problems when a resolve conflict doesn't?

Comment: @STP The merger. The person who worked on the branch is most likely to know what stays and what goes. If a coworker is merging your work, they may see a code deletion and think its an accident. Also when you merge a branch, you're merging a "completed" feature, and not WIP code. The conflicts that get solved are long term and not just mid development woes.

Comment: Then it appears if you are switching to feature branches it would take a few iterations to ensure that you don't run into the exact same issues as when you didn't . . . to me. Second question. How do I notify people that I have added a branch for them to pull into their local build? I assume once they do that initially that if I commit changes to it they will get subsequent notifications. I'm just fuzzy on how to do it through git/bitbucket/etc initially

Comment: _"In a perfect world you will branch from master, do your work, make your commits, and open a pull/merge request to QA. Once reviewed your code is deployed to QA"_ - possibly.  Release Management tools like _Octopus_ and _DevOps_ (though the former makes it easier) allow for _release promotion_ whereby the `same set of binaries` are used for all stages instead of making a special branch/PR/build for say **TEST/UAT/PROD**.  Otherwise you are testing one set of binaries in one stage and deploying another. +1 regardless